# Как добавить список в столбец SQLite запросом kotlin android

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, insert

У меня в БД 5 столбцов, 4 из них я заполняю запросом из сети. Пытаюсь добавить данные в базу конктретно в эти 4 столбца через `@QUERY`, т.к. при попытке сделать это через `@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)`, значение в 5 столбце устанавливается на дефолтное.

Хотелось бы через sqlite запрос вставить в столбец cписок целиком, то есть в id `List<Int>` в first_name `List<String>` и т.д. ? Возможно ли такое, если да, то как будет выглядеть правильный синтаксис? На данный момент я заполняю даннные через цикл for.

Вот запрос:

```
@Query("INSERT INTO friends_table (id, first_name, last_name, photo) VALUES (:id, :firstName, :lastName, :photo)")

suspend fun insertAll(
        id: Int,
        firstName: String,
        lastName: String,
        photo: String
    )
```

Comment: Либо заполнять как-то 5й столбец и вставлять список объектов insertAll(List<MyObject>), либо пятый столбец вынести в отдельную таблицу и сделать с ним связь по id и опять-таки в методе вставки использовать список.

Comment: @YuraIvanov благодарю за ответ, попробую исправить